# What's wrong with this following Tkinter program?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to execute my first tkinter app, but it's giving me error as shown below. Any idea why 'frame' is not visible to a function of the same class ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Data\Personal\Python\Tkinter\GUI_ver1.py", line 25, in <module>
myapp = App(root)
File "C:\Data\Personal\Python\Tkinter\GUI_ver1.py", line 7, in __init__
self.createWidgets()
File "C:\Data\Personal\Python\Tkinter\GUI_ver1.py", line 10, in createWidgets
self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
NameError: global name 'frame' is not defined
```

My program below:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "right"})

    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()
# create the application
myapp = App(root)

myapp.master.title("My First App")
myapp.master.geometry('450x130')
myapp.master.resizable(0,0)

# start the program
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
```

The `frame` you defined in `__init__` is not visible in any other methods. If you want to be able to access it, you need to make it an attribute of `self`.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
```

Don't forget to include the `self.` whenever you use the variable.

```
def createWidgets(self):
    self.button = Button(self.frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.frame.quit)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.hi_there = Button(self.frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
    self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
```

---

That's the easiest way to resolve the NameError, but your code will still crash with an `AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'master'` error. This is happening because, although you made `App` a subclass of `Frame`, you never call the `Frame` initializer for it, so it gets confused when you try to invoke Frame methods. Remember to call `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    self.createWidgets()
```

---

With that last addition, your code should work properly, but it's a little more complicated than it needs to be. Your `App` instance is a frame, but it also contains a frame within itself, `self.frame`. You could simplify this by removing the second frame and just adding widgets directly to `self`.

```
class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(self, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "right"})
```